# XSLT document() function where remote object is identified by a variable - possible workaround?

Tags: xml, function, xslt, command-line, document

I have been successfully using a stylesheet to make calls to a remote web service via the XLST document() function. The URL of the web service requires parameters, which are set using variables. A typical document() call looks like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="document(concat(
                              'http://example.com/api/find/',
                              '?find=service_name&amp;term=',
                              $searchterm,
                              '&amp;type=',
                              $search_type))
                      //value"/>
```

This works fine using Oxygen with either Saxon-EE or LIBXML on the desktop. I want to transition this to a scripted workflow using perl. When run within the context of the script, the lookup silently fails. Similarly, if I try to transform a document using Saxon from the command line:

```
java -jar /Applications/oxygen/lib/saxon.jar test.xml my.xsl
```

the document() lookup fails.

I assume the failures in the scripted and command-line contexts are due to security, although I am not receiving any error messages.

**My question is:** Is cross-domain security the cause of the lookup failure, is there a potential workaround for this, or do I need to take another approach?

For information the data returned by the web service looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <result resultCount="1"> 
   <value>Search result value</value>
</result>
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you say "the document() lookup fails"? If so, which one exactly? Try to run Saxon from the command line with the `-t` option. And you could also try to debug using `<xsl:message select="document(concat('http://example.com/api/find/?find=service_name&amp;term=',$searchterm,'&amp;type=',$search_type))"/>` to see whether the loaded document has the contents you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. First, I added the xsl:message statement. Then running Saxon from the command line with the -t flag, processing terminates when it reaches the line with the document() call. The trace outputs `Building tree for [url] using class com.icl.saxon.tinytree.TinyBuilder` then `Loading com.icl.saxon.output.MessageEmitter`, followed by a string fragment (a value from the URL parameter $searchterm. In Oxygen processing also terminates, but the description shows the two expected values from the query response (both strings are URLs + #[val]). Issues with characters or URL encoding?

Comment: In your post you mention "Saxon-EE", the stack trace with `com.icl.saxon` suggests you use Saxon 6. I don't think with an XSLT 1.0 processor like Saxon 6 you can use `<xsl:message select="exp"/>`, with XSLT 1.0 you can only use content inside of the `xsl:message` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#message) e.g. <xsl:message terminate="no"><xsl:copy-of select="document(...)"/></xsl:message>`. So so far your description is rather confusing, it is not clear which version of Saxon you use.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Yes, Saxon is v. 6.5.5 from both Oxygen and command line. With the xsl:message and <xsl:copy-of select="document(..." I now see the expected XML response from the web service in the Oxygen description: `<result resultCount="1">
  <valueURI>http://example.com/string#text</valueURI>
</result>`. However running from the command line I get a different response: `<noresult><searchterm>[string]</searchterm></noresult>` so it seems the service received only a fragment of the search term, that is, up to the first space character.

Comment: Where do you set the parameter or variable named `searchterm`? Do you do that on the command line? Is there any white space in the parameter value?

Comment: Depending on the command line you might need to put the parameter value with spaces into double or single quotes.

Comment: The parameters refer to the key=value paris in the URL query string. I have found that translating space to plus sign addresses the issue. I appreciate your help and an approach to troubleshooting I had not experience of previously.